# Error in using BeautifulSoup in Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to get a list of Amazon best sellers.
Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

def main():
    html_parser = HTMLParser()

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/").read())

categories = []

# Scrape list of category names and urls
for category_li in soup.find(attrs={'id':'zg_browseRoot'}).find('ul').findAll('li'):
    category = {}
    category['name'] = html_parser.unescape(category_li.a.string)
    category['url'] = category_li.a['href']

    categories.append(category)

del soup

# Loop through categories and print out each product's name, rank, and url.
for category in categories:
    print category['name']
    print '-'*50

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(category['url']))

    i = 1
    for title_div in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'zg_title'}):
        if i ==1:
            print "%d. %s\n    %s" % (i, html_parser.unescape(title_div.a.string), title_div.a['href'].strip())
        i += 1

    print ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
for category_li in soup.find(attrs={'id':'zg_browseRoot'}).find('ul').findAll('li'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Why am I getting this error and how to resolve it?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You also have other problems with your code, but to start off with the problem is if there are no objects with `id='zg_browseRoot'`, the first `.find()` will return `None`.

Comment: Thanks, but why does it return `None`?

Comment: Many reasons - maybe your `urlopen()` call is returning some other page than the Amazon page (for example, if you are behind a proxy it might be giving you a proxy error).

Comment: @TJ1 try to save `urlopen().read()` result to file and check what you actually get...

Comment: Thanks: I used debugger and looked at what `urlopen().read()` returns and it correctly returns the page I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the content from your second soup as well:

```
for category in categories:
    print category['name']
    print '-'*50

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(category['url']).read())
...
```

It gave me some pretty nice output.

Comment: The error happens before reaching to this part. Are you saying you could run the code? Are you using Python 2, or Python 3? Thanks.

Comment: Really? I did not have any problems and I am using Python 2.7

Comment: correct and my output looks like this for all the categories on the left:

Appliances
--------------------------------------------------
1. GE MWF SmartWater Compatible Water Fi...
    http://www.amazon.com/MWF-SmartWater-Compatible-Filter-Cartridge/dp/B00KJ07SEM

Comment: Thanks then there must be something wrong in my Python setup?